# Python Initialize multidimensional numpy array of random value

Tags: python, numpy

If I want to bulid a 3-dimensional array
And I can write something like this (x is the 3-dimensional array)

```
for i in range(pN): 
    for j in range(C): 
        for k in range(K+1):
            X[i][j][k] = random.uniform(0,1) #random initialize
```

But how can I make this code to be more readable? (For example, don't use 3 for loop)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use numpy random function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

It will generate random array of a shape you want (like 3x2x3)

```
 np.random.rand(3,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.random((pN,C,K))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy instead.

First install it with

```
pip install -U numpy
```

In terminal or windows command prompt.

Then in python program import it with:

```
import numpy as np
```

And then use `random.rand`:

```
np.random.rand((pN,C,K))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (x, y, z))
# x, y, z would represent the size of each dimension
```

[From the numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)